# Zend Documentation: How to see inherited methods and properties

Tags: php, zend-framework

The Zend API documentation does not show inherited methods and properties.  I'm using Netbeans, which does not show them either.

What's the best way for me to get this info (without trawling through the relevant files each time I use them)?  The only option I can think of is to regenerate Zend's API documentation with PHPDocumentor, or something similar...

Thanks for you ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type Hierarchy` View is there for Netbeans after 6.9.1

See the blog post http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/type_hierarchy

May be this also helps http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_MembersAndHierarchyPopup

Comment: Thanks Hari K T!  Right you are.  For other readers, remember that the Zend Framework must be on the include_path for it's classes to show in the navigator.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually planned to be added to DocBlox (and thus the Zend Framework API docs); you can view details of this at https://github.com/mvriel/Docblox/issues/74

I am trying to push this for the next version but it might be the one after that.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhpStorm IDE. It has some good features, that NetBeans has not. For your question you can use `"Type hierarchy"` tool. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Great idea. I use Eclipse for the same purpose.